# How to publish only selected NuGet packages from Azure Pipeline to Artifactory?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines, artifactory

I am using the Azure DevOps task **ArtifactoryNuGet@2** in an Azure Pipeline.

I need help deploying NuGet packages from an Azure Devops pipeline to Artifactory. (I don't know if it makes a difference, but this is a cloud instance of Artifactory, not an on-prem instance.)

I have read the documentation at these two sites:

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JFrog.jfrog-artifactory-vsts-extension
- https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Azure+DevOps+Extension

In addition, I have reviewed the task parameters in https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-azure-devops-extension/blob/master/tasks/ArtifactoryNuget/Ver2/task.json

I have successfully restored packages from Artifactory and pushed packages to Artifactory, using ArtifactoryNuGet. However, I want to fine-tune the push package path to exclude a certain directory. That is, I want to push all packages found in the directory `myproject` except for the packages found in subdirectory `myproject/foo` .

I have the task specified like this:

```
  - task: ArtifactoryNuGet@2
   enabled: false
   inputs:
    command: 'push'
    artifactoryService: 'AzureToArtifactory'
    targetDeployRepo: 'acm-nuget-release-local'
    targetDeployPath: 'Azure_CI_Build/xyzzy/packages'
    pathToNupkg: 'myproject\**\*.nupkg;!myproject\foo\**\*.nupkg'
```

While ArtifactoryNuget recognizes the double-wildcard '**', it doesn't recognize the exclusionary character '!' , and I don't know if it recognizes the semicolon ';' .

If I only use the path `myproject\**\*.nupkg`, ArtifactoryNuGet finds 15 packages, 11 of them in `foo` and 4 of them in other subdirectories. I only want the 4 found elsewhere.

If I use the path with the exclusions as in the example above, ArtifactoryNuGet does not find any packages. I expected it to find the 4 packages.

How can I define `pathToNupkg` to exclude certain subdirectories, as shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to using the [JFrog CLI task](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Azure+DevOps+Extension#ArtifactoryAzureDevOpsExtension-ExecutingJFrogCLICommands) as suggested by another here, you also have the option of using the [Artifactory Generic Upload task](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Azure+DevOps+Extension#ArtifactoryAzureDevOpsExtension-UploadingGenericArtifactstoArtifactory), right after the [Artifactory NuGet task](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Azure+DevOps+Extension#ArtifactoryAzureDevOpsExtension-TriggeringNugetand.NETCoreBuilds) generates the artifacts. Just like the JFrog CLI task, it supports exclusions as well as many other options, but allows defining everything through [file specs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-UsingFileSpecs).

Answer (score 3):

> How to publish only selected NuGet packages from Azure Pipeline to Artifactory?

You could try to use the [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI) task to publish package with option `--exclusions`：

[CLI for JFrog Artifactory-Uploading Files](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory)

[image]

```
jfrog rt u "myproject\**\*.nupkg" my-local-repo --exclusions="myproject\foo\**\*.nupkg*"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked and did what I needed to do. Was the first answer I checkmarked.